# How to see headers of urllib OpenerDirector before using open method

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm getting "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized" after trying this code:

```
_HTTPHandler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()                

_HTTPHandler.add_password(None,'http://192.168.1.205','admin','password')
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(_HTTPHandler)
opener.open('http://192.168.1.205/api/swis/resource')
```

I'm sure that the user/password is correct. I've tested it with [Google's postman app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) setting a Basic Auth header and i receive the correct response.

My question is how can a see the headers that are being used by the "opener" so i can check if they are being generated correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

For manual debugging, you can set the `debuglevel` of your `HTTPHandler`:

```
handler = HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)
```

This will produce rich output in stdout, where you can see the full request/response dump:

```
send: GET / HTTP/1.1
      Accept-Encoding: identity
      Host: www.example.com
      Connection: close

reply: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
header: Date: Mon May 22 2017 12:21:31 GMT
header: Cache-Control: private
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Relevant docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html

Comment: debuglevel is just for HTTPSHandler. I want to see headers with password in Basic Authentication (HTTPBasicAuthHandler)